# Python Command Output Terminal

Tags: python, redirect, command-line

This question is most likely on here somewhere, and anyone who can redirect me, that would be great.

But I can't find it - most likely not sure which appropriate key terms to use as everything gives me the python command line interpreter.

But I simply want to be able to use the output from a python as the input to another program from the command line. For example:

```
./program `python print 'A' * 100`
```

However, I get an error of:

```
python: can't open file 'print': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: Interesting collection of other redirection options in python, worth a read, [here](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/redirecting-all-kinds-of-stdout-in-python/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `python` executable with no switches expects no arguments(for an interactive shell) or a *.py file to run

you can use the `-c` switch to pass in code

```
./program `python -c "print 'A' * 100"`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
python -c "print 'A' * 10" | ./program
```